# SQL WHERE, OR and AND

Tags: sql

I'm trying to `SELECT` from this database `WHERE` either `statement_from` OR `username` is = to `$username` however this isn't working correctly. I have looked at previously asked similar questions however unsure how to implement the previous answers into this query.

```
   "SELECT * FROM `usr_statements` WHERE `statement_from` = '$username' 
    OR `username` = '$username' AND `statement_timestamp` > '$start_date'
    AND `statement_timestamp` < '$end_date' ORDER BY `statement_ref` DESC"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to select all the results in the database where the `statement_from` or the `username` is = to `$username`.

Comment: You can do `... where $username in (statement_from, username) ...` to make code more obvious!

Comment: It is more common to see date ranges defined with greater than or equal, such as `>= $start_date AND statement_timestamp < $end_date`

Comment: @Used_By_Already that is very true. I'm assuming that If a transaction was made on the exact second that the next statement date was generated it wouldn't show on either of the statements.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, you mean `statement_timestamp between $start_date and $end_date`?

Comment: No actually i don't. Between is a poor choice for date ranges imho. The more accurate approach is use >= followed by < plus note that MySQL does now support time precision finer than second so 23:59:59 does not accurately define the end of day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently your query is validated like this

```
WHERE `statement_from` = '$username' 
    OR (`username` = '$username' AND `statement_timestamp` > '$start_date')
    AND `statement_timestamp` < '$end_date'
```

because `AND` has *higher* precedence than `OR` so `AND` will be evaluated first.

You need to add proper parenthesis

```
SELECT * FROM `usr_statements` 
WHERE (`statement_from` = '$username' 
    OR `username` = '$username') 
   AND `statement_timestamp` > '$start_date'
   AND `statement_timestamp` < '$end_date' 
ORDER BY `statement_ref` DESC
```

Also you can use `IN` operator to do this as mentioned by *Jarlh* in comments

```
SELECT * FROM `usr_statements` 
WHERE $username in (statement_from, username)
   AND `statement_timestamp` > '$start_date'
   AND `statement_timestamp` < '$end_date' 
ORDER BY `statement_ref` DESC
```

Comment: Just the brackets then ahaha, I really appreciate the fast response. Thankyou.

Comment: I would say the same, please add the logical operator priority to be complet ;)

Comment: Thankyou for changing your answer to explain the higher and lower precedence that operators have it was really useful and think it will help me understand the order of operators in the future.

Comment: @LewisDay - Gald it helped you

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of operators is `NOT` -> `AND` -> `OR`, so you need some parentesis here:

```
"SELECT * FROM `usr_statements` WHERE (`statement_from` = '$username' 
    OR `username` = '$username') AND `statement_timestamp` > '$start_date'
    AND `statement_timestamp` < '$end_date' ORDER BY `statement_ref` DESC"
```